# Why does this cshtml result in a compilation error? (CS1061)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Book a showing";
    var db = Database.Open("calcinema");
    var f = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Film WHERE FilmID = 1;").ToList();
}

<html>
    <p> @f.Title </p>
</html>
```

The line being highlighted as wrong is

> @f.Title

If you can't see from the code what I am trying to do - basically there is a database table called Film and each Film has an ID. I just want to display the Title of the film with the FilmID = 1 (this film exists and I get the correct result when I run the query in webmatrix's database section). What have I done wrong?

Comment: "not work"  Could you go into more detail?

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired and been working on this site for ages. Didn't realize how vague the title was! I'll update the original post

Comment: Separate to the problem you're having, your should be doing your query in the Controller and passing the data to the View via a model (i.e. MVC).

If the query is supported to return a single item, you should be using `.First()` rather than `.ToList()` as well.

Comment: @martin_costello There are no Controllers or Views in ASP.NET Web Pages sites.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the tag saying it was a website, so assumed it was MVC.

Answer (score 1):

`f` is going to be a list of some Dynamic Type <strike>Anonymous Type</strike>. It's not going to have a `Title` property. Either you're thinking about embedding `Page.Title` in the cshtml or you need to iterate over each result in the list and write a `<p />` per element.

You may also be able to use `QuerySingle` <strike>`Single`</strike> to get the film (I chose single based on the fact that you're querying based on an ID and the query should return exactly one result):

```
var f = db.QuerySingle("Select * from film where filmid = 1");
```

Comment: There is a method on the Database class that is designed to return one result: `QuerySingle`. That should be used instead. And f is not an anonymous type. It's a dynamic type - specifically an instance of DynamicRecord

Comment: @MikeBrind - Updated with the corrections. I missed the WebMatrix tie-in here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Query` method with the Database helper, you get a collection of dynamic objects in return. If you only want one row to be returned, you should use the `QuerySingle` method instead which returns a single dynamic object:

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Book a showing";
    var db = Database.Open("calcinema");
    var f = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Film WHERE FilmID = 1;");
}

<html>
    <p> @f.Title </p>
</html>
```

You can read more about the Database helper methods here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data and I have written about the methods and their return types in more detail here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/214/How-To-Check-If-A-Query-Returns-Data-In-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer below. You can output all of the titles in the list using a foreach. But currently you are trying to select a property that doesn't exist on the list.

```
foreach(var film in f) 
{
   <p> @f.Title </p>
}
```

This would work otherwise try using

```
var f = db.Query("Select * from film where filmid = 1").SingleOrDefault();
```

I would personally use SingleOrDefault as it is normally "safer".

Comment: The "answer above" may not always be above!